# PyQt find checked radiobutton in a group

Tags: python, pyqt

Currently trying to write a function to return the checked radiobutton from a group of radiobuttons in python, but no success so far.

PyQt Gui code:

```
    self.hlw_customer = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.grb_main)
    self.hlw_customer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 26, 361, 21))
    self.hlw_customer.setObjectName("hlw_customer")
    self.hlb_customer = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.hlw_customer)
    self.hlb_customer.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.hlb_customer.setObjectName("hlb_customer")
    self.rdb_customer1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.hlw_customer)
    self.rdb_customer1.setObjectName("rdb_customer1")
    self.hlb_customer.addWidget(self.rdb_customer1)
    self.rdb_customer2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.hlw_customer)
    self.rdb_customer2.setObjectName("rdb_customer2")
    self.hlb_customer.addWidget(self.rdb_customer2)
    self.rdb_customer3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.hlw_customer)
    self.rdb_customer3.setChecked(True)
    self.rdb_customer3.setObjectName("rdb_customer3")
    self.hlb_customer.addWidget(self.rdb_customer3)
    self.rdb_customer4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.hlw_customer)
    self.rdb_customer4.setObjectName("rdb_customer4")
    self.hlb_customer.addWidget(self.rdb_customer4)
```

function to find the checked radiobutton:

```
def find_checked_radiobutton(self):
    ''' find the checked radiobutton '''
    enabled_checkbox = self.hlw_customer.findChildren(QtWidgets.QRadioButton, 'checked')
```

But sadly this returns []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

```
    self.find_checked_radiobutton(self.hlw_customer.findChildren(QtWidgets.QRadioButton))

def find_checked_radiobutton(self, radiobuttons):
    ''' find the checked radiobutton '''
    for items in radiobuttons:
        if items.isChecked():
            checked_radiobutton = items.text()
            return checked_radiobutton
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, and figured out this way:

```
import PyQt.QtGui as qg

boxElements = self.MainWindowUI.groupBox.children()

radioButtons = [elem for elem in boxElements if isinstance(elem, qg.QRadioButton)]
        for rb in radioButtons:
            if rb.isChecked():
                checkedOnRb = rb.text()
```

I like your solution. Here's another using findChildren which I learned thanks to the OP solution.

```
    rigTypeRadioButtons = self.MainWindowUI.groupBox_rigType.findChildren(qg.QRadioButton)
    rigTypeRb = [rb.text() for rb in rigTypeRadioButtons if rb.isChecked()][0]
    print 'rigType is: ', rigTypeRb
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it worked for me. I enumerated the button group list and checked if any of the buttons is clicked or not.

```
def test(self):
    checked_btn = [button.text().ljust(0, ' ').lstrip() for i, button in enumerate(self.btnGrouptab1.buttons()) if button.isChecked()]
    print(checked_btn[0])
    return checked_btn[0]
```